# Presenting a modal view controller within a modally presented view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, xcode7, modalviewcontroller

How to get a modally presented view controller present another view controller modally? I tried calling another modal view controller using presentViewController but the view controller does not appear.

e.g.

From within a modally presented view controller:

```
MessageViewController *vc = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithType:type];

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

// Modal view does not appear
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present a view controller, a property of the view controller will be set.

`presentedViewController` will be set. You need to call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on top of `presentedViewController`. You cannot present on already presented view controller.